# How to unshare folders that are inside of a shared folder?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server

I have this folder three in Windows Server 2012:

```
Projects
   |-> A
   |-> B
   |-> C
    ...
   |-> X
   |-> Y
   |-> Z
```

I want to share the folder `Projects` with `Programmers` group, but not all folders, only specific ones.

After share `Projects` folder i am trying to select all folders that are inside it and use `Share with -> Stop share`, but all users of the group `Programmers` still can use the folders.

I am starting to use this SO now, so it probably is a noobie question, but i will be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: Do it the other way.  Share folders within the parent directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot "unshare" child folders if the parent folder is shared.

Your best bet is to change the permissions on the folders. So for the folders you do not want programmers to access, remove their permissions on the folder, or explicitly deny them rights to the folder. Removing permissions is typically what is done; denying permissions is *usually* avoided.